# undefined reference 'to vtable for Hal'

Tags: c++, class, virtual-inheritance

```
class Allatok
{
    protected:
    char tipus;
    std::string nev;
    int kedv;

    public:
    Allatok(char c, std::string nev, int szam): tipus(c), nev(nev), kedv(szam) {}
    virtual ~Allatok() {}
    char Tipus() const {return tipus;}
    std::string Nev() const {return nev;}
    int Eletkedv() const {return kedv;}
    virtual int Kedv(char pistakedv) = 0 ;
};

class Hal: public Allatok
{
    public:
    Hal(char c, std::string nev, int szam) : Allatok(c,nev,szam) {}

    protected:
    int Kedv(char pistakedv);       //ha nincs kifejtve a cpp-be vrtable hibát dob
};
```

Comment: I included this header file to the main.cpp and the main.o was made then this error message popped up.

Comment: You need to implement `Hal::Kedv` (or include into the build the cpp file where it's implemented)